# How to display success message at top of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been dealing with this problem for a while, I have a script where users can make confessions and the way they do it is by clicking on a button which opens up a form, and when they publish it the alert sucsess message appears, but I can only display sucsess message in that div, and I want to display it at the top of the page, how can I achieve that?

JS for my alert messages:

```
 $('.alertMsg .alert-close').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                        INSERT INTO
                                            confessions(
                                                userId,
                                                firstName,
                                                confessText,
                                                postDate,
                                                hasImage,
                                                isActive,
                                                postIp
                                            ) VALUES (
                                                ?,
                                                ?,
                                                ?,
                                                ?,
                                                ?,
                                                ?,
                                                ?
                                            )
                    ");
                    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',
                        $user,
                        $firstName,
                        $confessText,
                        $postDate,
                        $hasImage,
                        $isActive,
                        $postIp
                    );
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $msgDiv = alertBox($confPosted, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "success");
                    // Clear the Form of values
                    $_POST['firstName'] = $_POST['confessText'] = $_POST['answer'] = '';
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            } else {
                $msgDiv = alertBox($captchaErrorMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
                $toggleOpen = ' in';
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how i display it, but my html code is pretty big and I will post just how I display it and in which section

```
<section id="page-title">
        <?php if ($msgDiv) { echo $msgDiv; } ?>
        <div class="container" id="container2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 title togglePanel">
                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="panel-toggle">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-confess btn-icon" id="confessToggle" data-perform="panel-collapse">Leave confession</a>
                                </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-wrapper collapse<?php echo $toggleOpen; ?>">
                        <center><div class="panel-body fessup-form">
```

So when they make confession they just click on LEAVE CONFESSION and the button slide down and they can fill out the form and submit, after they submit it redirects them on home page and it shows sucsess message just under the LEAVE CONFESSION button

FORM:

[image]

SUCCESS MSG:

[image]

So I don't want to display it in a page title section, I want to display it at the top of the page. Can I achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really more about CSS.  You can pop a div to the top of the page by making it fixed or absolute (depending on nesting).  Something like:

```
<div class="alertMsg" style="height:100px; width:100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background:green;"> test</div>
```

Ideally your should have the css in a separate file, but the inline css should demonstrate what I'm talking about.  Considering the class in your javascript and the styling you went with, below is my best guess at what you need.

```
.alertMsg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #505c86;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Its not working, as you can see the sucsess message is inside another div and needs to be shown at the top

Comment: A fixed element is relative to the viewport.  If you can't attach it to the top of the page, then your div must exist inside of an iframe, in which case your viewport for that particular item is constrained to the iframe.  If this is the case, and you still want the message at the top of the screen, you will need to send your message to the parent page, and not the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

On the submission of the form you can call *showMsg()* to see that Success message in action.

Hope the following line of code will help you.

```js
function showMsg()
{
$("#alertMsg").fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
  });
}
```

```css
.alertMsg
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
border: 1 px solid;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertMsg" id="alertMsg">Success</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<button onclick="showMsg()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Its not working on my webpage, as I said my success msg is inside another div, and I already tried position absolute but that doesnt help...

Comment: Is your  <?php if ($msgDiv) { echo $msgDiv; } ?> this line is on the same page where you inserting confessions in table ?

Comment: As you can see in my code php msgDiv line is in page-title section, and thats the section of the form, where it needs to be to output success message. I tried position absolute but then its not displaying anything. Do you happen to have email so I can send you more images and code and you can help me further? Thanks man

Comment: change your $msgDiv = alertBox($confPosted, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "success"); line to just $msgDiv=true; and your this line <?php if ($msgDiv) { echo $msgDiv; } ?> to <?php if ($msgDiv) { echo 'this is message'; } ?>
and check if you are getting that message

Comment: i can share my email but once you try by yourself

Comment: When I do what you did it displays this is message text, what do I do next?

Comment: I tried putting it in a div and setting position:absolute and top: 0 but still it wont show. It can only be seen in post title section.

Comment: ok sajjadramzan1211@gmail.com its my email address, you can share your code.
then i will return back to you after fixing issue

Comment: Ive sent you mail.

Comment: check you mail box